# Grouping pairs into multiple sets without using double loop in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

The data has multiple test cases which contain unknown pairs of points from graph belongs to different components (no. of components is dynamic as well).

I tried to use vector to store multiple sets(for each components), but due to multiple components exist, it still need another loop to put the points in different components. I got suggestions to use heap or tree but I couldn't figure out how to implement.

In C++, is there a way without using double loop to find the no. of points in the biggest group? Need a solution with time complexity better than O(n^2). Thanks

For example,
Input:

```
{1,2}
{2,4}
{2,3}
{4,3}
{9,8}
{7,8}
{6,7}
{7,5}
```

there are total 2 groups of points {1,2,3,4} & {5,6,7,8,9} and the biggest group has 5 points.
Output: `5`

Another example:

```
{1,2}
{2,3}
{8,9}
{6,7}
{7,8}
{4,5}
```

there are total 3 groups of points {1,2,3},{4,5} & {6,7,8,9} and the biggest group has 4 points.
Output: `4`

Comment: By "group" do you mean [component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))?

Comment: by group i mean, if we draw the endpoints on a graph, endpoints in same group will be at least have 1 edge connecting each other

Comment: You coud use the [boost graph library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html). The complexity is specified with O(V+E), where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges. You could also implement the algorithm yourself using a breadth-first or depth-first search. That should be quite straigthforward (just counting the vertices). The search will stop if you visited all the vertices in one component at which time you reset the counter and start with the next unvisited vertex.

Comment: @JoN: I agree with Thomas. Graph Theory is well-established, the question here is really how your data should be interpreted. For instance, you say "endpoints" which suggests that the edges consist of a beginpoint and an endpoint, i.e. they're directed edges. But this is not made explicit in the question.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks for correcting, it is not a directed graph. endpoints I mean simply points

Comment: @JakobStark I think i cannot use boost library, or any library other than std, the compiler is C++ 11, -static -std=c++0x.

Comment: @JoN: Boost Graph is header-only, you don't need to link a library.

Comment: @MSalters how to include the header if I can only use 1 cpp file? I tried the following example and the compiler said "No such file or directory" of the .hpp https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/graph/example/connected_components.cpp

Comment: Use a `std::map`. Map the points to group objects. Each group stores a list of points so far. Do one pair after the other. First check, whether 0, 1, or 2 points are already in map. If 0, create new group, if 1, add point to group, if 2 and they belong to different groups, merge the two groups. Should run in O(n²) for maximum number of merges I think.

Comment: @JoN: You will need to tell the compiler which include directory to use. It won't search your entire harddisk. See existing questions here on StackOverflow for your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithm for finding components in a graph is using a simple graph traversal algorithm. You could use breadth-first or depth-first search for example.

First you have to convert the graph representation you provided (called an edge list) into a structure, that is better suited for graph traversal. For example you can use an adjacency list, that is a map which maps each node to a list of other nodes it is connected to.

The following example does all that and spits out the number of nodes in the largest component.

```
int find_largest_component(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& edge_list) {
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> adjacency_list {};

    // build an adjecency list of the undirected graph
    for ( auto it : edge_list ) {
        adjacency_list[it.first].push_back(it.second);
        adjacency_list[it.second].push_back(it.first);
    }
    
    int component_count {0};
    int largest_component {0};

    // a queue for breadth first search
    std::queue<decltype(adjacency_list)::value_type> Q {};
    while ( !adjacency_list.empty() ) {

        // push a single node to queue and remove it from graph
        Q.push(std::move(*adjacency_list.begin()));
        adjacency_list.erase(adjacency_list.begin());

        while ( !Q.empty() ) {
            // pop a node from queue
            auto v = std::move(Q.front()); Q.pop();
            component_count++;

            // loop over neighbours
            for ( auto n : v.second ) {
                auto h = adjacency_list.find(n);
                if ( h != adjacency_list.end() ) {
                    // found a neighbour that is still in the graph
                    // (and thus not yes visited). Push it to the queue
                    // and remove it from the graph
                    Q.push(std::move(*h));
                    adjacency_list.erase(h);
                }
            }
        }

        // update the largest component count if we found a larger one
        if ( component_count > largest_component ) {
            largest_component = component_count;
        }
        component_count = 0;
    }

    return largest_component;
}
```

Note that while the pure breadth-first search is O(V+E) in theory, I used `std::map` which is usually implemented as a red-black tree. This solution is thus not optimal. If your nodes can be numbered consecutively, you could use a `std::vector` instead of a `std::map` for the adjacency list and use indexing rather than searching for finding the nodes.

You can find a live example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G4G9axqeT)